# Hardware Keyboard is not working in Xcode Simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I just installed the React Native App on Xcode Simulator but when i am trying to type in the Text Input it doesn't work. Anyone have the answer?

I tried re-running the simulator but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Run Command<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>(Shift) + <kbd>K</kbd> while in the simulator. This solution worked for me.